# Search A Stored List With Similar Values

Tags: python, search

I have my search function working partially. If I have a stored machine value of 123 it will pull the first 123 from the list rather than every entry that matches 123 like I want it to.

```
def search_Machine(machine):
    findIdex = 0
    for i in buckets:
        if i[1] == machine:
            return findIdex
        findIdex += 1
    return -1
```

I need it to search and show every entry with the matching value the user inputs. If that makes sense.

```
elif a == 5:
    Machine = input("Enter machine: ")
    import os

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    bktIndex = search_Machine(Machine)
    if bktIndex >= 1:
```

Entire script below:

```
buckets = []
count = 0


def export_bkt(buckets):
    fopen = open("PushoutBuckets.txt", "a")
    for bucket in buckets:
        for i in bucket:
            fopen.write(i + " ")
        fopen.write("\n")
    fopen.close()


def import_bkt(fname):
    temp = []
    fopen = open(fname, "r")
    for line in fopen:
        line = line.strip(' ')
        if len(line) != 0:
            line = line.split(',')
            temp.append(line)
    fopen.close()
    return temp


def Add_Bucket():
    global count
    Bucket = []
    count += 1
    print('Enter group number: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter machine: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter hookup type: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter capacity: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter width: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter profile: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter weight: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter notes: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter coupler type: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    print('Enter large notes: ', end='')
    Bucket.append(input())
    buckets.append(Bucket)
    import os
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")


def view_all_Buckets(buckets):
    for i in buckets:
        print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print('Group Number: ', i[0])
        print('Machine: ', i[1])
        print('Pin On / Coupler: ', i[2])
        print('Capacity: ', i[3])
        print('Width: ', i[4])
        print('Profile: ', i[5])
        print('Weight: ', i[6])
        print('Notes & Updates: ', i[7])
        print('Coupler Type: ', i[8])
        print('Large Notes: ', i[9])
        print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')


def search_GroupNumber(groupnumber):
    findIdex = 0
    for i in buckets:
        if i[1] == groupnumber:
            return findIdex
        findIdex += 1
    return -1


def search_Machine(machine):
    findIdex = 0
    for i in buckets:
        if i[1] == machine:
            return findIdex
        findIdex += 1
    return -1


def main():
    global count
    global buckets


while True:
    print("----------------------------- Pushout Buckets ----------------------------------\n")
    print('Enter -1 to exit')
    print('\nThere are (', count, ') buckets in the database.')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('1. Add new bucket.\n')
    print('2. View all buckets.\n')
    print('3. Edit bucket information.\n')
    print('4. Search bucket by group number.\n')
    print('5. Search bucket by machine.\n')
    print('6. Search bucket by hookup type.\n')
    print('7. Search bucket by capacity.\n')
    print('8. Search bucket by width.\n')
    print('9. Search bucket by profile / fixture.\n')
    print('10. Search bucket by weight.\n')
    print('11. Search bucket by coupler type.\n')
    print('12. Search bucket by notes & updates.\n')
    print('13. Export bucket information into a text file.\n')
    print('14. Import bucket information from a text file.')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
    print('Please enter your option number: ', end="")
    a = int(input())
    import os

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    if a == -1:
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        quit()
    elif a == 1:
        Add_Bucket()
        print()
    elif a == 2:
        view_all_Buckets(buckets)
        print()
        input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    elif a == 3:
        Machine = input("Enter the group number of the bucket you would like to update: ")
        bktIndex = search_Machine(Machine)
        if bktIndex >= 0:
            buckets[bktIndex][0] = input("Enter Updated Group Number: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][1] = input("Enter Updated Machine: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][2] = input("Enter Updated Pin On / Coupler: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][3] = input("Enter Updated Capacity: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][4] = input("Enter Updated Width: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][5] = input("Enter Updated Profile: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][6] = input("Enter Updated Weight: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][7] = input("Enter Updated Notes & Updates: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][8] = input("Enter Updated Coupler Type: ")
            buckets[bktIndex][9] = input("Enter Updated Large Notes: ")
            print("\nBucket information has been updated successfully.\n")
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        else:
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
            print("Bucket with " + Machine + " is not found.\n")
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    elif a == 4:
        GroupNumber = input("Enter Group Number: ")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        bktgroup = search_GroupNumber(GroupNumber)
        if bktgroup >= 0:
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print('Group Number:', buckets[bktgroup][0])
            print('Machine:', buckets[bktgroup][1])
            print('Pin On / Coupler:', buckets[bktgroup][2])
            print('Capacity:', buckets[bktgroup][3])
            print('Width:', buckets[bktgroup][4])
            print('Profile:', buckets[bktgroup][5])
            print('Weight:', buckets[bktgroup][6])
            print('Notes & Updates:', buckets[bktgroup][7])
            print('Coupler Type:', buckets[bktgroup][8])
            print('Large Notes:', buckets[bktgroup][9])
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        else:
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
            print('Invalid Option.\n')
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    elif a == 5:
        Machine = input("Enter machine: ")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        bktIndex = search_Machine(Machine)
        if bktIndex >= 1:
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print('Group Number:', buckets[bktIndex][0])
            print('Machine:', buckets[bktIndex][1])
            print('Pin On / Coupler:', buckets[bktIndex][2])
            print('Capacity:', buckets[bktIndex][3])
            print('Width:', buckets[bktIndex][4])
            print('Profile:', buckets[bktIndex][5])
            print('Weight:', buckets[bktIndex][6])
            print('Notes & Updates:', buckets[bktIndex][7])
            print('Coupler Type:', buckets[bktIndex][8])
            print('Large Notes:', buckets[bktIndex][9])
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        else:
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
            print("Machine " + Machine + " not found.\n")
            input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
            import os

            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")


    elif a == 13:
        export_bkt(buckets)
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        print("Data Successfully Exported.\n")
        input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    elif a == 14:
        buckets = import_bkt("PushoutBuckets.txt")
        count = count + len(buckets)
        print("Data Successfully Loaded.\n")
        input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    else:
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        print('Invalid Option.\n')
        input("Press ENTER to return to the main menu.")
        import os

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")

main()
```

Comment: Are the values you are searching for in the employees list?

Comment: Here is what the user inputs, then the program can return to the main menu and the user can select the option to search for the information below base on what they input for "machine". The search function works initially but it will only pull up the first entry that matches the input value, rather than every entry.

Group Number:  4560D1
Machine:  CAT980
Pin On / Coupler:  Coupler
Capacity:  6.5Cyd
Width:  120
Profile:  2
Weight:  3800
Notes & Updates:  None
Coupler Type:  Fusion
Large Notes:  None

Comment: so a dictionary or a list? formatted like... {'Group Number: 4560D1', 'Machine: CAT980 Pin On'... }? Please post the data structure to your question.

Comment: It's a stored list that the user inputs. I'm new to this and it is hard to explain without just sending you the entire code to view. I can do that if that would help explain things better.

Comment: Happy to help. The user inputs a list? Or, the user inputs a string and you want to see if that string is in the list? The example input you gave is '123', so in that case the user would loop through the list, example ['123', '456', '789'] to check if the input '123' is in the list. Sound correct?

Comment: The user inputs all of the information and it is stored in an empty list. The user can then search for all of the information on a given entry by entering the machine number. However, rather than pulling up all of the group numbers that fit the same machine, it will only pull up the first found entry. I can share the entire program with you if you'd like, or invite you if you use PyCharm.

Comment: The "user inputs all of the information" is vague. Yes, if you want help, post all of your code, correctly formatted.

Comment: Try this link. Formatting within this post will take forever lol.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/mjack360/shares/db221b70b0b446bcbb70ebb799ec3849/

Comment: I can't access that URL. To be frank, if you don't have the time and motivation to post and format your code, how can you ask others to use their time to help?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the entire script. (I found a quicker way to format it correctly.)